# Implementation with pthread works, but not with std::thread: a thread blocking my mainloop function

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I tried yesterday to use std::thread correctly, but it's very dark for me.

My program implementation with pthread works well I don't have any problem with it. I would like to have the same solution with std::thread (if possible).

Solution with pthread:

```
void *MyShell(void *data) {
  std::string str;

  while(1) {
    std::cin >> str;

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

  }
}

void mainloop() {
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, aed::map::shell::Shell, this);
  ...
  pthread_cancel(thread);
}
```

And now the solution which doesn't work everytime, with std::thread:

```
class ShellThreadInterrupFlag {
  public:

    void interrupt() {
      throw std::string("Thread interruption test\n");
    }

};

class ShellThread {
  public:

    template<typename FunctionType, typename ParamsType> 
    ShellThread(FunctionType f, ParamsType params) {

      std::promise<ShellThreadInterrupFlag *> p[3];
      _internal_thread = new std::thread(f, p, params);
      _flag = p[0].get_future().get();
      _internal_thread->detach();
      p[1].set_value(_flag); // tell the thread that we detached it
      p[2].get_future().get(); // wait until the thread validates the constructor could end (else p[3] is freed)
    }

    ~ShellThread() {
      delete _internal_thread;
    }

    void interrupt() {
      _flag->interrupt();
    }

  private:

    std::thread *_internal_thread;
    ShellThreadInterrupFlag *_flag;
};

void Shell(std::promise<ShellThreadInterrupFlag *> promises[3],
           aed::map::MapEditor *me)
{
  ShellThreadInterrupFlag flag;

  promises[0].set_value(&flag); // give the ShellThread instance the flag adress 

  promises[1].get_future().get(); // wait for detaching
  promises[2].set_value(&flag);   // tell ShellThread() it is able to finish

  while(1) {
    std::cin >> str;

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }
}

void mainloop()
{
  ShellThread *shell_thread;

  shell_thread = new ShellThread(Shell, this);

  ... // mainloop with opengl for drawing, events gestion etc...

  shell_thread->interrupt();
}
```

Sometimes, when I launch the program, the `std::cin >> str` is called and the mainloop is blocked.

Does anyone know why the thread is blocking my mainloop ? And how could I avoid this problem ?

Comment: Pthread cancellation raises a signal in the target thread, and the target thread has an appropriate signal handler installed. Your code is doing something totally different -- throwing an exception is a synchronous operation.

Comment: I don't have problems on the cancellation, when the mainloop is not blocked by the other thread, it interrupts the thread without problems. The problem is that the code between `shell_thread = new ShellThread(Shell, this);` and `shell_thread->interrupt();` is sometimes blocked by the other thread, and I can only use the shell, not my window with the opengl context.